# How to store integer to variables in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I would like to store numeric value to variable and use it later in Lookup as parameter, but failing to store value to variable.

1. I have "Lookup", which makes: Select Count(CustomerId) as customer_rows From Customers. It returns value 15.
2. I have variable customer_rows, which is string (since no integer or float available)
3. I have "Set Variable" with value: @activity('SelectCustomers').output.firstRow.customer_rows

I get error:
The variable 'customer_rows' of type 'String' cannot be initialized or updated with value of type 'Integer'.
The variable 'customer_rows' only supports values of types 'String'.

Comment: Have you try converting the value using `@string`? i.e. `@string(activity('SelectCustomers').output.firstRow.customer_rows)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since lookup activity output would be considered as array, you would have to access, array elements using index.

[image]

Just use as below value to set to a variable. (modify index as per your output)

```
"@{activity('SelectCustomers').output.value[0]}"
```

Example:

Query: `SELECT count(username) as counts FROM [dbo].[job_details]`

[image]

Set variable value:

```
"@{activity('Lookup query').output.value[0]}"
```

[image]

[image]